In Star Trek: 2009, why did Pike get promoted?
I get that the out of universe reason would be that Kirk had to be captain and all that, but is there a canonical answer to why Pike would have been promoted at the end of Star Trek 2009? It seems that he did very little other than get captured and not giving out secrets.

Frame challenge: Promotions are not "awards for doing something exceptional" but are routine pathways based on tenure of competent service.

He's not probably not promoted because of anything he did during the movie, but things that happened during the movie are probably a factor.
Note that Pike was clearly on the rise well before his promotion to Admiral - he's the Captain of a flagship, and that's the kind of job that goes to some expected to be an Admiral someday. But you can't get promoted to admiral until there's an empty admiral level position to be filled.
During the course of the movie Nero destroys a major Federation planet (Vulcan) and at least seven Federation vessels. It is reasonable to suspect that a large number of flag officer positions became available for senior Captains like Pike.

Plus they needed to take his ship away from him to give to Kirk

Plus that - because destiny

The British navy used to operate solely on seniority, so how good a captain you were didn't really matter too much when it came time to promote someone to admiral. (Most of my understanding of this comes from Patrick O'Brien's Aubrey-Maturin series, but https://www.napoleon-series.org/military-info/organization/Britain/Navy/c_flagranks.html seems to be a more in-depth description of the system--and its attempted reforms).
